# How to filter by "answered"?

Tags: support, questions, filtering

There is a "No answers" filter.

Is there an "Answered" filter?
[image]

Comment: You can use the main search and include the `isaccepted:1` parameter. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching)

Comment: @AlonEitan `hasaccepted:1` would be better as it returns the questions rather than answers

Answer (score 13):

Advanced search allows filtering in more ways:

[`hasaccepted:1`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hasaccepted%3A1&mixed=1) will return questions with an accepted answer only.

[`is:question answers:1`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+answers%3A1&mixed=1) will return any answered questions.